# ErrorException in Filesystem.php

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5

**Issue with session storage**

Session storage not working with my Laravel 5. Used it for a month without problems. But since latest upload to web server I get the following response on every page.

```
ErrorException in Filesystem.php line 74:
file_put_contents(): Exclusive locks are not supported for this stream
```

Many posts on the internet are indicating to remove the reference to

```
$lock on line 74 in Filesystem.php
```

Seems like a quick fix which will lead to other issues down the road...

**How do I take care of the root cause?**

**References**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29023948/laravel-5-file-put-contents-exclusive-locks-are-not-supported-for-this-stre
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/l5-new-install-error

Comment: Additional links (did not have enough reputation)

https://github.com/octobercms/october/issues/969
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/8007#issue-61873798

Comment: Wait, you're putting your session data on a cloud filesystem? Bad idea.

Comment: I had this problem today with 4.2 and your quickfix has worked. Likewise, it was working before, but uploading today has caused this problem. I am pretty sure this is because of a recent (buggy) Laravel update as I did a `composer update` within the last week.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

after update do

```
chmod -R gu+w storage

chmod -R guo+w storage

php artisan cache:clear
```

Comment: @maleeb you only need to run one 'chmod' command: `chmod -R a+w storage`. You're overwriting group and user 'write' permissions in the second command. its superfluous.

Answer (score 20):

If you use Laravel 5.2.0 you've probably ignored the `storage` folder in the `.gitignore` file. The thing is that when you run `composer install` on your server not all the files from the storage folder are created, you should check those !

In my case my storage folder contained only the `logs` folder without `app` and `framework` folders. You need to create those manually so you should have this structure at the end:

```
storage
  - app
  - framework
    - cache 
    - sessions
    - views
  - logs
```

Don't forget to make the `storage` folder writable !

Comment: My installation was simply missing the session folder.

Answer (score 6):

Had to do with the hosting. My cloud service did not support exclusive locks. I exchanged

`return file_put_contents($path, $contents, $lock ? LOCK_EX : 0);`

to

`return file_put_contents($path, $contents, $lock ? LOCK_SH : 0);`

on line 74 of Filesystem.php

Comment: Great solution. Thanks! I exchanged return file_put_contents($path, $contents, $lock ? LOCK_EX : 0); with return file_put_contents($path, $contents, $lock ? LOCK_SH : 0); on line 74 of Filesystem.php works like a charm.

Comment: Is it safe to do so?

Answer (score 5):

thanks @peder-wessel. Your answer is the cause explanation but not a permanent solution and will work until we update the vendors again as Filesystem.php file is inside Laravel vendor directory. One day, when we `composer update` it will cause problem again. :(

However I was able to find out that this issue is caused because Session is saved to file. I changed this from

```
'driver' => 'file',
```

to

```
'driver' => 'cookie',
```

in **/app/config/session.php**

Maybe laravel creators should add this to configuration too, as not all (shared) hostings provide exclusive lock rights

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and renaming or removing the

`/bootstrap/cache/config.php`

file(file name) is working for me.

This file containes/caches the local server configuration which conflicts with the remote server.

Hope this will help. All the best.

Answer (score 1):

`php artisan config:cache`
could help and is probably a better way than removing `bootstrap/cache/config.php`, it updated it.
If your server works in docker container, be careful, if you have a volume to share with host and run command on host, it put host paths in config.php, paths that doesn't exist in container…
so connect to container and run it inside

Answer (score 0):

I had problem with publishing my assets from my package with this error
file_put_contents(): Exclusive locks are not supported for this stream

this package helps [NoLock](https://github.com/hasangilak/NoLock)