# Laravel 5.2 : file_put_contents (xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.php) failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have installed fresh Xampp, And set the virtual host, When i accessed the site, The following error came up.

`file_put_contents(/b237142d7ac388af2fe193a8361f611a83409dff.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied`.

I searched for the issue, Folk says that its /storage permission issue i have changed the permission to `sudo chmod -R 777 /site-name/storage`.

But the issue still remains.

Am i missing something ?

Comment: file_put_contents('/site-name/storage/b237142d7ac388af2fe193a8361f611a83409dff.php') ?

Comment: the content perhaps?

Comment: `/b237142d7ac388af2fe193a8361f611a83409dff.php` is in filesystem root; and your pplication should not have permissions too write there. If you prefix a filename with `/`, that makes it absolute, not relative

Comment: You need to give writing permission to web-server user to all directories in the path, not just the last one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `storage` folder,`app`, `framework` folders were missing, By adding them the issue is gone and now things are working like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a Laravel 5.2 project. I already had the folders `app` and `framework` in `storage` folder. Then I found that in `framework` folder you need to have three folders: `cache`, `views` and `sessions--` and make sure `storage` folder has the write permission.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35152223/2866984) helped to solve the problem finally.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.