# Laravel: file_put_contents() failed to open stream: Permission denied for Session folder

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am getting this issue for sessions even when I have given 777 and required user and group to the folders in storage.

ErrorException in Filesystem.php line 81: file_put_contents(/var/www/html/business/storage/framework/sessions/2b184c1b05d6d2af943d9a4e48875301321a56ec): failed to open stream: Permission denied

How can I get rid of this issue?

> at HandleExceptions->handleError('2',
>   'file_put_contents(/var/www/html/business/storage/framework/sessions/2b184c1b05d6d2af943d9a4e48875301321a56ec):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied',
>   '/var/www/html/business/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php',
>   '81', array('path' =>
>   '/var/www/html/business/storage/framework/sessions/2b184c1b05d6d2af943d9a4e48875301321a56ec',
>   'contents' =>
>   'a:5:{s:6:"_token";s:40:"Dyi8ML8zxaQJOEiVvqBpqk3noLDJTkIdqiC67qs9";s:9:"_previous";a:1:{s:3:"url";s:29:"http://XXXXX:8333";}s:22:"PHPDEBUGBAR_STACK_DATA";a:0:{}s:9:"_sf2_meta";a:3:{s:1:"u";i:1470895812;s:1:"c";i:1470895812;s:1:"l";s:1:"0";}s:5:"flash";a:2:{s:3:"old";a:0:{}s:3:"new";a:0:{}}}',
>   'lock' => true))

Comment: Have you given a recursive change of permission of all the folders in storage? Could possibly work if you do `chmod -R 777 storage`.

Comment: All done and even issue still same

Comment: Maybe this troubleshooting checklist will help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: Possible duplicate of [file\_put\_contents(meta/services.json): failed to open stream: Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23540083/file-put-contentsmeta-services-json-failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied)

Answer (score 89):

I had a problem like that and doing the following solved it for me

```
chmod -R gu+w storage

chmod -R guo+w storage

php artisan cache:clear
```

Got it from the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29195786/7607526)

Comment: if none of this is working even after performing all steps mentioned by geneowak then clear browser cookies and cache. it worked for me.

Comment: I am using a VPS
`chmod -R guo+w storage`  did it for me. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

First run this command in your Laravel app folder

```
sudo composer update
```

After that run the following in order

```
sudo chown -R $USER:www-data storage

sudo chown -R $USER:www-data bootstrap/cache

sudo chmod -R 775 storage

sudo chmod -R 775 bootstrap/cache
```

Answer (score 2):

if you try

> chmod -R gu+w storage
>
> chmod -R guo+w storage
>
> php artisan cache:clear

and it still doesn't work.

you have two ways:

1. Disable your SELinux (i really don't recommend this way, unless you are on training or learning)
2. Configuring SELinux Policies for Apache Web Servers

i want to break down every steps for confirguring selinux policies
assumption: you've already installed all database like mysql, postgresql, or others. you've installed web server

> 1. install semanage with command "yum provides /usr/sbin/semanage"
> 2. install policycoreutils-python with command "yum install -y policycoreutils-python"
> 3. create policies:
>
> > a. sudo semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_content_t "/var/www/html/webapp(/.*)?"
> >
> > b. sudo semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_log_t "/var/www/html/webapp/logs(/.*)?"
> >
> > c. sudo semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_cache_t "/var/www/html/webapp/cache(/.*)?"
>
> 4. Allowing ReadWrite Access:
>
> > a. sudo semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t "/var/www/html/webapp/storage(/.*)?"

ACCESS YOUR WEBAPP

> > b. restorecon -Rv /var/www/html/webapp

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you. Specially the command: restorecon

Answer (score 1):

```
chown -R www-data:www-data project_folder
sudo service apache2 reload
```

Answer (score 0):

```
chmod -R gu+w storage
chmod -R guo+w storage
php artisan cache:clear
```

This worked for me for my laravel 8 application.

Comment: The same as @geneowak. Delete the duplicate awnser or add more content!

Answer (score 0):

Giving 777 to the folder session works for me.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: This is NOT a good approach to define 777 permissions. It's a security risk to your application and system. Please read this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/20105/why-shouldnt-var-www-have-chmod-777

Comment: @Saud , Why is it not secure while this system requires it? i tried from 000 to 777, and only 777 worked. :(

Comment: @TranQuocBao It is considered bad because it allows all the privileges for a file. Means anyone can read and execute your files/scripts which is not that bad, but anyone can also modify your file, which is totally bad. Its the same reason you put a password on your mobile device. Anyone can see your phone. Use your phone to call emergency numbers, but they can't perform any other action. I've mentioned the answer above to better understand. Please read it from there, I can only explain very little in this comment box. Good Day! :)

Comment: The question says "I have given 777". Apparently that didn't work. Simply saying that it worked for you is not helpful at all.

Answer (score 0):

run  the following command
`docker-compose exec <your webserver container name> sh` OR `bash`(if it uses bash)
then

```
ls -l /var/www/storage/framework/views/ | grep 7369b96b4 (this number is part of the file name you are trying to see it permission) you will see something like this -rw-r--r--
```

the run

```
chmod 777 var/www/storage/framework/views/7369b96b436adb2109e56fbb8ed7ba805568c985.php(the full file name)
```

reload the page

Answer (score 0):

Go to the session folder and make the permission like 755. It's worked for me.

Comment: Answer needs to be more descriptive

Answer (score 0):

late but I hope this will help someone else.
in my case, after I added the `/storage/framework` line to the `.gitignore` file, I faced this error.
so then I removed it from `.gitignore` file and everything back to normal.

Answer (score -1):

Goto project root folder and run the following command

```
sudo chmod -R 777 storage/* bootstrap/cache/*
```