# Laravel 5 show ErrorException file_put_contents failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, windows, laravel, laravel-5

I have a project on Laravel 5 and I work with it at the office and at home too. It works fine, but recently at home it stopped working. Laravel show me two ErrorException

```
file_put_contents(G:\project\storage\framework\views/751d8a0fd8a7d4138c09ceb6a34bb377aa2d6265.php):
failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

and

```
file_put_contents(G:\project\storage\framework/sessions/aIXycR4LIAUBVIqZu0T590paOMIpV8vfZGIroEp0):
failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

I'm searching problem decision with Google and find information about correct rights. All advice is about Linux, but I'am work in Windows at the office and at home too.

When I try to clear application cache and view cache, artisan talk to me - ...cleared. But cache data and views are present in storage.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Yo can try cleaning the cache
"php artisan cache:clear"
I'm on linux, so I'm not sure about permission on windows, but check on folder properties if it's not read_only (right click on folder->properties)

Comment: @educolo I don't think the problem is about directory rights, because several month it was ok.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [file\_put\_contents(meta/services.json): failed to open stream: Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23540083/file-put-contentsmeta-services-json-failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied)

Comment: This solved my problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/72911821/7519779

Answer (score 68, accepted):

After some research I understand - I have very similar, but different root project locations and its cached in `/bootstrap/cache`. After cache clearing project started.

Comment: Wish I had seen this as it's the answer to my question about a missing service provider: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58192052/laravel-spark-google2fa-provider-class-not-found-after-spark-update-to-v9-0

Answer (score 220):

The best way to solve this problem is, go to directory `laravel/bootstrap/cache` and delete `config.php` file. or you can rename it as well like `config.php.old`
And your problem will be fixed.

Comment: Yes that would help, but clearing the cache can do the job. Run outside the Vagrant Box `php artisan config:cache` will rebuild paths for the applications. When we are running application inside the vagrant box, paths are different to paths for dusk tests for example.

Comment: Why does laravel's config make laravel die? Works thanks.

Comment: config:cache didnt fix for some reason.

Comment: Clean, Simple, and direct for those that cant access via SSH at the time, or in general. Great answer!

Comment: config:clear works for me beside the renaming the file works too,

Comment: I did like 5 times `php artisan config:cache` did not work but deleting the config.php from laravel/bootstrap/cache did the trick

Comment: Why does laravel's config make laravel die? Works thanks

Comment: It will work for shared hosting user, just don't run any terminal command after deleting just upload the project on to the server.

Comment: deleting config.php from the bootstrap folder is working for me

Comment: `mv bootstrap/cache/config.php bootstrap/cache/config.php.old` worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: The best answer among all.

Answer (score 84):

You should typically run the `php artisan config:cache` command as part of your production deployment routine. As a solution to your problem, I suggest you recreate the cache file, for faster configuration loading.

To do this, run the following Artisan commands on your command line

- `php artisan cache:clear`
- `php artisan config:cache`

You can programmatically execute the command by adding the following to your routes:

```
Route::get('/clear-cache', function() {
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('cache:clear');
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('config:cache');
    return 'DONE'; //Return anything
});
```

And then call the `clear-cache` route from your browser.

Comment: From at least Laravel 8 `config:clear` both clears and caches so there's no need to run two different commands.

Answer (score 24):

Actually I faced this issue when I moved my project from server to local.

in

> storage/framework

four basic folders are required cache, sessions, testing, views

In My case sessions was missing might be in gitignore.

So I manually created session folder and refreshed browser and it was working.

So any of the missing folder if we delete this problem can be solved.

Answer (score 15):

I solved this problem via creating `storage\framework\sessions` folder.

Comment: This folder there was before in this path, I just emptied that and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 10):

## Apache + WSL on windows

This is a silly mistake, and a different answer compared to the others, but I'll add it because it happened to me.

If you use WSL (linux bash on windows) to manage your laravel application, while using your *windows* apache to run your server, then running any caching commands in the wsl will store the *linux path* rather than the *windows path* to the sessions and other folders.

### Solution

Simply run the cache clearing commands in the ***powershell, rather than in WSL.***

```sh
$ php artisan optimize
```

Was enough for me.

Comment: I ran into the same issue. I'm running Windows and also an instance of Linux on a VMWare virtual machine. This allows me to test both on Windows and Linux, but when I ran the `php artisan config:cache` command on Windows, my Linux would no longer load the application's web pages. Going into the bootstrap/cache folder and deleting the config.php file there resolved it.

Answer (score 7):

This type of issue generally occurs while migrating one server to another, one folder to another. Laravel keeps the cache and configuration (file name ) when the folder is different then this problem occurs.

Solution Run Following command:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/configuration#configuration-caching

Answer (score 6):

Try with these commands that have been useful with those errors

*path\project\storage\framework\views...*

```
php artisan view:clear
```

path\project\storage\framework/sessions...

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: If you post a new answer while there are already multiple upvoted answers, you should add some more explanation to it such that others can learn from your answer

Answer (score 4):

In case of shared hosting when you do not have command line access simply navigate to `laravel/bootstrap/cache` folder and delete (or rename) `config.php`.

Answer (score 4):

I deleted the file `/public_html/bootstrap/cache/config.php`

Then I ran `php artisan config:cache`

Answer (score 3):

If you are running laravel inside docker then access its filesystem

```
$ docker exec -it name-of-laravel-container /bin/bash
```

Next navigate to your laravel projects root directory. Make sure that you have inside **storage/framework** folder:

1. cache
2. sessions
3. testing
4. views

And they should be both readable and writable.

Answer (score 3):

This happens when you shift your website from local to live server or vice versa.
Simply go to `bootstrap/cache` and delete config.php.

Comment: The top answer seems to suggest this already.  Try to only add new information when posting answers to posts.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is related to cache or permission.

Firstly, go to directory **laravel/bootstrap/cache** and delete all files from cache.

1. php artisan cache:clear
2. php artisan config:clear
3. php artisan config:cache

If the errors still happen. It may relates to permission
Let's try command below (In my case user&group of laravel is nginx)

```
sudo chgrp -R nginx storage bootstrap/cache
sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this problem is the cache files in localhost. According to that I've tried several things as follows to clear the cache on my project, but every time I've failed.

- Tried to clear cahe commands by changing web.php file (with artisan codes)
- Tried to clear cache by connecting SSH (via PUTTY)
- Tried to host my project in Sub domain within create a new *Public* directory

So I've found a solution for this problem after each and every above steps failed and it worked for me perfectly. I deleted the **cache.php** file in **host_route/bootstrap/cache** directory.

Answer (score 2):

Changing name of `/bootstrap/cache/config.php` to `config.php.old` doesn't work for me
neither clearing cache with the commands artisan

1. php artisan config:clear
2. php artisan cache:clear
3. php artisan config:cache

And for some weird reason I can't change permission for the owner on the directories, so my solution was running my IDE (Visual Studio Code) as admin, and everything works.

My project is in an F:/ path of another disk.

Answer (score 2):

If nothing work try the following in the production environment

1-

```
composer install --optimize-autoloader --no-dev
```

2-

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

3-

```
php artisan config:clear
```

4-

```
php artisan view:clear
```

5-

```
php artisan config:cache
```

6-

```
php artisan route:cache
```

Works for me

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is an issue with your composer file. You could try:

> - **composer install** installs the vendor packages according to    composer.lock (or creates composer.lock if not present),
> - **composer update** always regenerates composer.lock and installs the    lastest    versions of available packages based on
>   composer.json
> - **composer dump-autoload** won’t download a thing. It just regenerates    the list of all classes that need to be included in the
>   project   (autoload_classmap.php). Ideal for when you have a new class
>   inside your project. Ideally, you execute composer dump-autoload -o ,
>   for a  faster load of your webpages. The only reason it is not
>   default, is  because it takes a bit longer to generate (but is only
>   slightly noticeable)

Above content originally quoted from [Robin Brackez, What does ‘composer dump-autoload’ do in Laravel?](https://web.archive.org/web/20141216130302/https://developed.be/2014/08/29/composer-dump-autoload-laravel/)

Answer (score 1):

Clearing the contents of `storage/framework/cache` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it clearing the content of:

> /laravel/storage/framework/views

Then all the views were created again in that folder.

In my case these commands didn't fix it:

```
php artisan view:cache
php artisan route:cache
php artisan config:cache
```

I'm using Laravel 8 and in my case it seems that it was an issue with the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was not anything that could be fixed with php artisan commands. The issue was folder permissions for the /storage folder. The error did not make that clear.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me is to just serve the app as admin
if you are

1. On `mac` or `linux` use `sudo php artisan serve`
2. On Windows try to open `CMD` as an `adminstrator` and then go to project directory and run `php artisan serve`

Answer (score 0):

### For failing tests

I got this error when I made the mistake of deleting the `tests/console` folder along with the `tests/source` folder - specifically I was getting the following error from the Dusk tests running on my CI/CD environment (GitHub Actions):

> ErrorException: file_put_contents(/home/runner/work/mysite/mysite/tests/Browser/console/Tests_Browser_MyDuskTest1_test_payments_are_working-0.log): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory

`tests/source` is an optional folder whereas apparently the `tests/console` is not and needs to exist in order for Dusk integrated tests to run.

I'm not sure why Dusk doesn't just create the folder dynamically when writing the console logs to disk, but either way, restoring the deleted `console` folder in the `tests` directory fixes the issue. If you can no longer restore the deleted folder, just creating the `console` folder with an empty `.gitignore` file in it should have the same effect.

Answer (score -1):

I had similar problems because of .gitignore for the `/storage` folder on first machine, then cloned repository on second machine and laravel was revision to write down sessions cache

So, manually creating folder `/storage/sessions` might be an solution..

Answer (score -1):

I used Laravel 8, This is my solution:

**Goto:

storage/framework/cache/data

set permission directory data is 777**

Answer (score -1):

This did the magic for me. chmod -Rf 0777 storage

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I set `APP_DEBUG=false` since it is a production server, I decided to set it back to `true` and then it showed `Missing BC Math or GMP extension`

That is how I solved my own issue, setting `APP_DEBUG=true` might not work for everybody.

Answer (score -1):

I went all the way, but I did not get the answer.
I just rename cache folder in `storage/framework/` to `cache1` and solved my problem.

Comment: This is the same as clearing the cache, which has already been mentioned https://stackoverflow.com/a/64413142/2227743

Comment: yes but clear cache not work for me. after rename cache folder fixed error.