# file_put_contents failed to open stream: No such file or directory , Install

Tags: php, laravel

i cloned a laravel  project from bitbuket . also run all necessary command to get all vendors files like :

```
composer dump-autoload
composer install
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan clear-compiled
```

also deleted the file /public_html/bootstrap/cache/config.php

but i am getting the below error when i try to launch the project :

> file_put_contents(C:\xampp\htdocs\laravelstart\storage\framework/sessions/sRPb1A6BKrshhH8HPAR2fXVEcCH4daYCLxgo4b8M):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: Could you please explain about your error and put your coding sample

Comment: you have tried already a possible solution, Please elaborate your question with more detail.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46959985/laravel-5-show-errorexception-file-put-contents-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-f  Did you try clearing the cache and then clearing your local cache before re-loading the page?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 show ErrorException file\_put\_contents failed to open stream: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46959985/laravel-5-show-errorexception-file-put-contents-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-f)

Comment: Hey, I know its been a long time. Can you please tell me how you were able to solve the problem?

Comment: I noticed that the slashes face two different directions in the file path. Is that just a mistake in the logging? Or could that be part of why it's not working?

Answer (score 10):

rm -rf bootstrap/cache/config.php (delete)

php artisan config:cache

Comment: i did , but the problem not fixed

Comment: try 

php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache

Answer (score 3):

There can be various reasons why that error happened.

1. Try to delete all cached files.

   `rm -rf bootstrap/cache/config.php`
   `php artisan config:clear`
   `php artisan cache:clear`
   `php artisan config:cache`
2. If the above actions does not work, then try this again.
   Give permission to the directories in storage directory:
   app, framework, logs

   `sudo chmod -R 777 storage/app`
   `sudo chmod -R 777 storage/framework`
   `sudo chmod -R 777 storage/logs`

Answer (score 1):

Try the command: `php artisan config:cache` it clear the configuration cache of your project. The problem may be that you cloned it, and the configuration is not prepared for your new server :)

Comment: i did , but the problem not fixed

Answer (score 0):

If cleaning cache doesn't work (that might happen when you running under docker for instance) try just `chmod 755 storage bootstrap/cache` again. It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

`cd` to your `/storage/framework/cache/data` or `/storage/framework/sessions` or any of the directories in the `framework` folder and type `ls -la`, you may see something like:

```
drwxr-sr-x  3 apache   apache   16 Oct 16 13:00 bd
drwxr-sr-x  3 apache   apache   16 Oct 16 17:38 be
drwxr-sr-x  3 root     apache   16 Oct 17 05:00 bf
drwxr-sr-x  3 apache   apache   16 Oct 16 13:07 c6
drwxr-sr-x  3 root     apache   16 Oct 16 16:15 d3
drwxr-sr-x  3 apache   apache   16 Oct 17 12:32 dd
drwxr-sr-x  3 apache   apache   16 Oct 17 12:32 e2
drwxr-sr-x  3 root     apache   16 Oct 16 16:00 e9
drwxr-sr-x  3 apache   apache   16 Oct 16 21:25 f6
drwxr-sr-x  3 apache   apache   16 Oct 16 16:56 f8
drwxr-sr-x  4 apache   apache   26 Oct 17 06:00 fa
```

As you can see some directories are owned by `root`, to fix this `cd` into the `storage` directory and run:

(first check which `user:group` you need, for AWS it could be `ec2-user:apache`):

```
sudo chmod 2775 . && sudo chown -R apache:apache . && sudo chmod -R og-r . && sudo find . -type d -exec chmod g=rwxs "{}" \; && sudo find . -type f -exec chmod g=rw  "{}" \; && sudo setfacl -d -m g::rwx . && sudo setfacl -d -m o::rx .
```

You may want to include this in your deployment script every time you push changes from your repo.

Answer (score 0):

Go to directory `laravel/bootstrap/cache` and delete config.php file.

Answer (score 0):

you can as well try this, it worked for me `php artisan optimize:clear`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, my problem was the name of the file was too long, you are naming your file like this: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravelstart\storage\framework/sessions/sRPb1A6BKrshhH8HPAR2fXVEcCH4daYCLxgo4b8M

I suggest:
Try using a shorter name. Or Try to save the file in the root without path. Or check if you are using the right slashes in your path or use a shorter path, in my case i used this: file_put_contents('./storage/pdfs/file.jpg');

Comment: Try using a shorter file name? YESSS!!! That did it! Who knew windows carried these flaws over to their server environments!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

But I did realized that the sessions directory was missing.

Ensure that you have the sessions folder.

`mkdir storage/framework/sessions/` - (linux)

Creating this directory fixed my issue.