# file_put_contents(C:\Users\FNRI\Desktop): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, laravel, deployment, directory, storage

How can I use a command like php artisan `clear:cache`, when deploying a laravel project in 000webhoso?

I tried to configured but still can't find out the solution

I need to clear the logs and cache, using migration

`php artisan clear:cache`

### Error:

> file_put_contents(C:\Users\FNRI\Desktop\final\storage\framework/sessions/Jutrm2SkTQTO8H0jB1wnGXm5y8HUd7siBBtjh8Jz): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

to get load my project

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 show ErrorException file\_put\_contents failed to open stream: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46959985/laravel-5-show-errorexception-file-put-contents-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-f)

Answer (score 2):

Go to directory **bootstrap > cache > config.php** Delete config.php file.

if you want to call `php artisan clear:cache` then you may create it route file as well

```
Route::get('/clear-cache', function() {
  Artisan::call('cache:clear');
            // return what you want
});
Route::get('/clear-view', function() {
  Artisan::call('view:clear');
            // return what you want
});
Route::get('/clear-config', function() {
  Artisan::call('config:clear');
            // return what you want
});
```

run as

- domainname.com/clear-cache
- domainname.com/clear-view
- domainname.com/clear-config

Answer (score 1):

That work at 100%
add to routes/web in your Laravel project
use: your domain/clear
for  solving any problems with cache

```
Route::get('/clear', function () {
Artisan::call('cache:clear');
Artisan::call('config:clear');
Artisan::call('view:clear');
Artisan::call('route:clear');
Artisan::call('clear-compiled');
Artisan::call('config:cache');

return '<h1>Cache facade value cleared </h1>';});
```

Comment: Please add explanation for your future answers. It helps people for understanding your code.