# laravel-spark-google2fa Provider class not found after Spark update to v9.0

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-spark

I recently updated a [Laravel/Spark](https://spark.laravel.com/) web application to the latest version of Spark (v`9.*`) via `composer`.  Another package I use is [Laravel-Spark-Google2FA](https://github.com/cretueusebiu/laravel-spark-google2fa) which I also updated from v`1.*` to v`2.*`.

**Setup:**

The laravel-spark-google2fa package has a Laravel service provider class that resides in `/project-root/laravel/spark/src/Providers/Google2FAServiceProvider.php`

In Laravel we specify this in `/project-root/laravel/config/app.php` with the following line in the `providers` array:

`Laravel\Spark\Providers\Google2FAServiceProvider::class,`

In `composer.json` we have:

```
"require": {
      ...
    "doctrine/dbal": "^2.5",
    "laravel/framework": "^6.0.0",
    "eusebiu/laravel-spark-google2fa": "^2.0.0",
    "laravel/cashier": "^10.0.0",
    "laravel/spark-aurelius": "^9.0.0",
    "laravel/tinker": "^1.0.0",
    "laravelcollective/html": "^6.0.0",
    "webpatser/laravel-uuid": "2.*"
},
"autoload": {
      ...
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
...
```

Note: aside from the higher version numbers you see above in the `require` section, this has been the setup for a long time with the web application running successfully during that time.

**Error:**

Since we upgraded `laravel/spark` to `laravel/spark-aurelius: ^9.0.0` we've run into one error which prevents the application from running:

```
In ProviderRepository.php line 208:

  Class 'Laravel\Spark\Providers\Google2FAServiceProvider' not found
```

**Failed attempts**

We have tried the following to fix this, none of which have worked:

- running `php artisan config:clear`
- running `php artisan cache:clear`
- running `composer dump-autoload`
- as per laravel-spark-google2fa docs, running `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Eusebiu\LaravelSparkGoogle2FA\Google2FAServiceProvider" --force`
- changing how the service provider is specified in `app.php`
- added a new path to `autoload` in `composer.json`
- downgrading `laravel-spark-google2fa` to an earlier version
- removing and re-installing `laravel-spark-google2fa`
- running `spark-installer` over the existing application

In all of the above cases the error remains, preventing the application from running.

The `laravel-spark-google2fa` package may be recently abandoned.  I opened an issue there and haven't heard a reply.  Laravel/Spark support has not suggested a solution.  So I am posting here as a last resort before getting rid of this package and refactoring my code to use a different one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was unaware of the bootstrap cache.  The bootstrap cache file contained a reference to the `Google2FAServiceProvider` service provider class which after various package updates and what not was no longer present.

Running commands like `php artisan config:clear`, `php artisan cache:clear`, and `composer dump-autoload` did not clear this cache.  In the end, I simply removed the offending file:

filename: `services.php`

location: `/laravel/bootstrap/cache/services.php`

`config.php`, in the same location, can also contain such references.

Note: I used the find feature in VSCode to look for references to this service provider and it did not find this one because the bootstrap cache is gitignored.