# Problem With laravell CACHE::Remember and key containning

Tags: php, laravel

Hello i Was advised on git hub to try to ask here.

When i use

```
Cache::remember("comment-".$comment->id."-project", 60, function () use ($filter) {
     return $filter->organization->id;
});
```

i get this error:

I even found where problem lies when folowing cache key is used: "filter-13-organization"
The file name should be this md5 hash: 3cfc118695be71111eebccec273a3665ba31fd37
but is 3c/fc/3cfc118695be71111eebccec273a3665ba31fd37 instead zou can notice 2 additional / in string formate whitch are then pased as 2 subdirectories whitch due not exists!

I was expecting that FIle in cache 3cfc118695be71111eebccec273a3665ba31fd37
wil dont have additiona / whitch will be than parsed as subddirectories and i get this error

[image]

Comment: The `3c/fc/` isn't changing a hash, it's subdirectories in the cache directory. Laravel does this to keep the cache directory organized.

Comment: `chmod -R 777 storage bootstrap/cache`

Comment: 777 isn't recommended, that makes it world-writeable. But https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38888568/laravel-file-put-contents-failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied-for-sessio/72911821#72911821 recommends 775

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639174/how-to-set-up-file-permissions-for-laravel might also help